# Stop animating navigation bar when pushing a segue

Tags: ios, navigation, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

I have navigation bar with a prompt in size. When pushing to a destination segue, my image set up in my navbar in the parent render the navbar animately to be the default on the child. How can I stop this animation and retain the size and the default style of the navigation bar in the child?

Comment: Or simply remove the image in the child after the push?

Comment: What is **prompt in size**? Why do you want to prevent animation?

Comment: I have a "navigation bar with prompt". That's a height of 74. When I switch views to child view, it animates to 44. (literally animating - moving to a size of 44).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `navigationBar` customization at

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

To reset the changes you can either return the default `navigationBar` settings at child view `viewWillAppear` or root view

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

A better choice depends on what you need.

Comment: i got it already..how can I get rid of the animation when switching to views?

Comment: Instead of using `setPrompt:` you can increase the `navigationBar` frame, add a subview `UILabel` and animate it for push/pop actions with `UINavigationControllerDelegate` or `UINavigationBarDelegate` depending on whether you are using `UINavigationController` or a standalone `UINavigationBar`. I don't have a sample to show but it must be a direction to search around.

Comment: Another solution for an `UINavigationController` is to hide it's `UINavigationBar` and to add your own `UINavigationBar` subview to the `UIApplication` instance `keyWindow`. This will not be animated with any nav-controller animations and you'll need to prepare all the animations yourself, be careful using this approach and don't forget that you are expected to bring about the same user-experience as with the standard `UINavigationController` implementation.